# Using Individual pieces of Backbone Marionette with RequireJS

Tags: marionette

I am looking to use Backbone Marionette in my application with RequireJS. It looks very promising,especially the Views and Regions. I would like to use them in my application but use some of the existing features already present in my application.

For example,I would like to use my existing Event Aggregator instead of Backbone.Wreqr. Can I do that? Is Backbone.Wreqr hard dependency for Marionette or can Marionette work without it?

Also I would not like to include pieces of Marionette that I do not plan to use in my application, like modules, templateCache, etc.

Is it possible to have a trimmed version of Marionette?

Thanks
Chintan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Marionette has hard dependencies on multiple libraries. From it's documentation:

> Prerequisites
>
> Marionette relies on Underscore, Backbone, jQuery, and various other libraries as its foundation.
>
> - JSON2.js
> - jQuery (v1.7, v1.8, v1.9)
> - Underscore.js (v1.4.4)
> - Backbone.js (v1.0.0)
> - backbone.wreqr.js
> - backbone.babysitter.js

As far as picking and choosing features, Marionette's code is split up nicely with each main feature in it's own file. You might be able to copy the repo and do one of the following:

1. AMDify each feature to use with requirejs
2. Piece together the files/features that you want and amdify the resulting combined file
3. Rip out the features that you don't want from the generated amdified file.

With any of the routes, be sure to get the dependencies between the features lined up correctly (i.e. Layout depends on ItemView, which depends on View, so you'll need to keep View and ItemView if you intend to use Layout).

Comment: Thanks! This is great info. However, it seems that Backbone.wreqr is very deeply integrated in Marionette code. So I have to include it if I use individual pieces from Marionette. IS that true?

Comment: It seems that you can use individual Marionette pieces separately, but not get rid of any of the pre requisites like backbone.wreqr.

Comment: You are correct. The only optional features that you can try to remove are actual Marionette features, not Marionette's dependencies.